# control home heating and light

Tags: relay

i am looking for a way to control the on/off of the heating element in my country house and a couple of lights. all i am looking for is to switch on or or off respectively the heating equipment and 3 lights. I would like to do it from my mobile, so when i will be at home after 3-4 hours it will be warm.
is there a guide on how to do it? i am looking also to have the state of each device. eg heating is on, or light on bedroom 1 is on.
At the moment i have a rpi 2 and the internet access ready on the house. looking for the rest.

Answer (score 1):

There is several projects for doing this, but the one that I like the most is [blynk](http://www.blynk.cc) (that I've recommended several times by now here and iot stack exchange)

I've a similar setup at home, where I've a node in the living room that reads a bosch bme280 sensor and controls a led strip with a mosfet (but the setup for a relay will be quite similar).

In the bedroom, I've two devices, a nodemcu with a bme280 and a sonoff s20. The nodemcu reads the temperature and humidity, and if the humidity is below a certain value, it will send a "message" to the sonoff that turns on the relay after the humidity readed is higher that a certain value.

Also, You can have charts and a lot of stuff to play with, which make it's a great environment to play with.